# Python Kraken API Add Order respond shows Egeneral:Internal error

Tags: python, api

I used Kraken API to place order using python.
I just simply copy&pasted the codes on the api sample site of Kraken.com
But I get empty datas and Error 'EGeneral:Internal error'.
And I checked that even the error respond is 200

Here is my code. apikey is removed from the code for security.

```
import time
import requests
import urllib.parse
import hashlib
import hmac
import base64

# Read Kraken API key and secret stored in environment variables
api_url = 'https://api.kraken.com'
api_key = '[My-API-key]'
api_sec = '[My-Secret-API-Key]'


def get_kraken_signature(url_path, data, secret):

    postdata = urllib.parse.urlencode(data)
    encoded = (str(data['nonce']) + postdata).encode()
    message = url_path.encode() + hashlib.sha256(encoded).digest()

    mac = hmac.new(base64.b64decode(secret), message, hashlib.sha512)
    sigdigest = base64.b64encode(mac.digest())
    return sigdigest.decode()

# Attaches auth headers and returns results of a POST request
def kraken_request(uri_path, data, api_key, api_sec):
    headers = {}
    headers['API-Key'] = api_key
    # get_kraken_signature() as defined in the 'Authentication' section
    headers['API-Sign'] = get_kraken_signature(uri_path, data, api_sec)             
    req = requests.post((api_url + uri_path), headers=headers, data=data)
    return req

# Construct the request and print the result
def get_account_balance():

    data = {
        'nonce': str(int(time.time()*1000))
    }

    resp = kraken_request('/0/private/Balance', data, api_key, api_sec)

    print('Account Balance')
    print(resp.json())

def open_orders():

    data = {
        "nonce": str(int(1000*time.time())),
        "trades": True
    }

    resp = kraken_request('/0/private/OpenOrders', data, api_key, api_sec)

    print("Open Orders")
    print(resp.json())

def place_orders():

    data = {
        "nonce": str(int(1000*time.time())),
        "ordertype": "limit",
        "type": "sell",
        "volume": 1.25,
        "pair": "XBTUSD",
        "price": 0
    }  

    resp = kraken_request('/0/private/AddOrder', data, api_key, api_sec)

    print('Place Order')
    print(resp.json())


get_account_balance()
open_orders()
place_orders()
```

It is just a test program so I do not have any balance in my account. Can the error 'Egeneral:Internal error' occur when my balance is 0?
Because of some reasons, I can't deposit to my account or use Kraken lib.

Comment: Idk your location or account restrictions, but I do not encounter any error when executing your code. The only problem is that you cannot place an order with a price of 0. The [python-kraken-sdk](https://github.com/btschwertfeger/python-kraken-sdk) will provide more information about the specific errors and provides all Spot and Futures API endpoints.